# How to call function in update statement

Tags: t-sql

I can get the first, middle, last name for a function passing a string. How do I pass the element in the query to the function for an update statement.

--test update logic, and name parsing

```
USE PCUnitTest
UPDATE p
SET    --Need FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME
       p.FIRST_NAME = SELECT forename FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser(c.CONTACT)) AS FirstName, --shows multipart identifier could not be bound
       p.FIRST_NAME = SELECT forename FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Andy D Where')) AS FirstName, --returns Andy
       p.MIDDLE_NAME = SELECT middle_name FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Andy D Where')) AS MiddleName, --returns D
       p.LAST_NAME = SELECT surname FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Andy D Where')) AS LastName --returns Where

FROM   GMUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1 c 
       JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.PEOPLE p
         ON p.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4   
         WHERE c.Key1 = '76';  --Test with a current string
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to do something similar to this:

```
USE PCUnitTest
GO

UPDATE P
SET
     P.First_Name = T.ForeName
    ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
    ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
FROM GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact) T
WHERE C.Key1 = '76'
;
```

I don't know what you're using to parse the names, but I can see that it always returns the first name, middle name, and last name.  You might want to consider adding an extra input parameter to your function so that you can specifically request the first, middle, or last name by entering a numerical (or other) parameter.

In the query up above, each name would return duplicate results, so you would probably end up running an `UPDATE` against the same value a few times, each time with the same value.

By adding another parameter to your function, you could use `CROSS APPLY` several times (or `OUTER APPLY` if there's a chance that one or more monikers are missing) in order to update more efficiently, as such:

```
USE PCUnitTest
GO

UPDATE P
SET
     P.First_Name = FirstName.ForeName
    ,P.Middle_Name = MiddleName.Middle_Name
    ,P.Last_name = LastName.Surname
FROM GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact,1) FirstName
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact,2) MiddleName
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact,3) LastName

WHERE C.Key1 = '76'
;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm using the JStyons. So you have to join to a table and you can't put a function in the set expression. I just have to figure out how to add to it to get suffixes like Jr, Sr. I saw the one using input parameters, I will try it too.

Comment: also, this is for a trigger, for insert after, when i reference the inserted table, which shows in the intellisence dropdown list when i type inserted i get the error, "the multipart identifier "inserted.contact" could not be bound". any idea how to reference the inserted table for a trigger?

USE PCUnitTest
GO

UPDATE P
SET
     P.First_Name = T.ForeName
    ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
    ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
FROM GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(inserted.Contact) T
WHERE C.Key1 = '76'
;

Comment: There's no problem referencing the `Inserted` table in a `TRIGGER`.  You just need to include it in the `FROM` clause of your query.  If you're having specific troubles with that, I would recommend updating your original question with the real query you're trying to run, or asking a new question based on the problem you're having.